# How to set BaseUrl for Swagger in ASP.NET Core Web API using NSwag.AspNetCore (when hosted behind a reverse proxy)

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, swagger, nswag

I am struggling with the following situation:

I have an ASP.NET Core Web API with the following Swagger configuration in Startup.cs:

```
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
      ...

      services.AddSwaggerDocument(config =>
      {
        config.PostProcess = document =>
        {
          document.Info.Version = "v1";
          document.Info.Title = "...";
        };
      });

      ...
    }

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
      ...

      app.UseOpenApi();
      app.UseSwaggerUi3();

      ...
    }
```

If I run the api locally everything works fine. Means I can access the Swagger page at `http://localhost:5000/swagger/index.html` and execute requests from there against the api which is available at `http://localhost:5000/api`.

On production, my api is running inside a Docker container and behind a reverse proxy. The container exposes the Swagger page at `http://localhost:5000/swagger/index.html` and the reverse proxy maps external requests to `https://my.domain.com` to `http://localhost:5000` internally. This way I am actually able to access the Swagger page at `http://my.domain.com/swagger/index.html`. So far everything is fine.

The issue is when I want to execute reqests against my api from that production Swagger page. I see in the network tab of the browser dev tools that Swagger still sends the requests to `http://localhost:5000/api` what of course does not work. Instead it should send the requests to `https://my.domain.com/api`. Also below the title, the Swagger page states `[ Base URL: localhost:5000 ]`.

I am not able to figure out how I could configure Swagger to use whatever base url I provide (like `https://my.domain.com/` in my current case) so that I could execute requests against the api from anywhere and also that the BaseUrl below the title would be correct.

Can anybody help me here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out myself meanwhile. The solution is to remove the localhost server (which is added by ASP.NET Core middleware) and to add my own one like this:

```
app.UseOpenApi(settings =>
{
  settings.PostProcess = (document, httpRequest) =>
  {
    document.Servers.Clear();
    document.Servers.Add(new OpenApiServer { Url = "..." });
  };
});
```

This Issue/Comment directed me in the right direction: https://github.com/RicoSuter/NSwag/issues/2441#issuecomment-583721522